# Using PyQ in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kdb, pyq

I am trying to use PyQ in Jupyter, a package designed to communicate between the Python and Q/kdb+ programming language. I am successfully able to install Q/kdb+ on my Windows computer (where the q.exe file is located in the standard C:), pip installed pyq, and opened Jupyter with Anaconda Navigator. However, when I create a new .ipynb notebook and attempted to initialize Q using PyQ, I am presented with:

```
ImportError: Importing pyq from stock python is not supported. Run path\to\q.exe python.q.
```

How do I fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [pyq-kernel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyq-kernel).

Please see [Installing Jupyter Kernel](https://pyq.enlnt.com/install/windows.html#installing-jupyter-kernel) for details.